# Do we ever see the actual Percival Graves?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In the movie Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, the excellent Colin Farrell plays Percival Graves, Director of Magical Security at MACUSA.

However, by the end of the movie, it is revealed that

> Gellert Grindelwald has been impersonating Graves for some time.

My question is:

### Do we ever see the actual Percival Graves in the movie?

#### Notes

- This question:
  [How did this Fantastic Beasts character disguise themselves?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145434/how-did-this-fantastic-beasts-character-disguise-themselves) uses a source that may provide the answer to my question, but it is not the same question and not the same answer. Other sources may be used to answer my question that could not be used to answer the other one.

Comment: You hide the part about Gellert Grindelwald, but your title makes it obvious Percival Graves we see isn't really Percival Graves...

Comment: True, but not that he is GG, which your comment now spoils. :) Thoughts on revision?

Comment: https://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/fantastic-beasts-david-heyman-reveals-graves-and-colin-farrells-futures-in-series-105821/#post12078998

Comment: The top answer on the duplicate question explicitly answers this.

Comment: @Valorum actually there is a line in passing in the other answer which answers this question but does NOT answer the other. Just because they're from the same source does NOT mean they're duplicates. Otherwise all LotR questions would be duplicates

Comment: @Edlothiad - The answer below and the answer in the dupe are **identical**. Let that be your guide

Comment: No they're not "**identical**" they come from the same source and have very different emphases. You could take out 90% of the waffle, and they'd be different, ibid just hasn't. Learn the policies.

Comment: @Edlothiad - The framing text is subtly different, but a small edit to the dupe question and answer would render this question entirely obsolete.

Comment: Look at the questions, and look at the answers "There was a real Graves. We didn't film him" Does not answer the other question. The rest of the quote could be removed for this question. I'd have removed it. The part from JKR is COMPLETELY irrelevant to this question.

Comment: As the OP, I am not sure I should get involved, but I find the two questions to be sufficiently different. One (my) question asks whether or not character A is ever actually in the movie, while the other asks how character B disguised himself as character A. Even though the two answers can come from the same source, the two questions (and their answers) are not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [According to producer David Heyman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rt-tK-RM2g), Graves does not appear in the movie and there are no plans for him to appear in future movies either.

> **SnitchSeeker: Is there a real Graves? what happened to him?**
>
> **David Heyman:** *That's a very good questions. I've been wondering ... I'm amazed more people haven't picked up on that. Yes, there was a real Graves. Yes, someone used some polyjuice potion and took their place. I don't know where they are at the story's end, **But yes, there was a real Graves. We didn't film him.** We didn't film the polyjuice. We just dived into the story midway through.*
>
> **SnitchSeeker: Will we see Graves in the future?**
>
> **David Heyman:** *I doubt it.*
>
> **SnitchSeeker: It is similar to what happened with Crouch and Moody in the fourth book.**
>
> **David Heyman:** *Yes.*
>
> **SnitchSeeker: I guess Colin Farrell won't be back in the sequel.**
>
> **David Heyman:** *There's no plans to bring Colin back for the sequel.*
>
> <sub>[David Heyman talks to SnitchSeeker about the real Graves & his fate in 'Fantastic Beasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rt-tK-RM2g)</sub>

Note that J.K. Rowling later clarified that the transformation wasn't actually done via polyjuice.

> **Why did ‘revelio’ undo the effects of Polyjuice Potion?**
> It didn’t. Grindelwald’s Transfiguration surpasses that of most wizards, so he used a spell, not a potion, to take on the appearance of Percival Graves.
> <sub>[J.K. Rowling's new website - FAQ](http://jkrowling.com/welcome-to-my-new-website/)</sub>